# What to do about furnace that's drawing gas odors into the room instead of heat?

Tags: heating, furnace, central-heating, gas, heater

I have a gas furnace.  It was heating up the place fine and worked for years until the other day.

All of a sudden it started drawing air that smelled like strong gas odors into the room rather than heat.

Is this repairable?  Is it something I can fix myself?

Answer (score 12):

**This is quite possibly an emergency.** Call your gas utility company and have them come check it out immediately. Also, open some windows to draw fresh air into your home, if you have a gas or exhaust leak it can be a fire and suffocation hazard.

Comment: Curses, I can only add one up vote.

Comment: More than a fire hazard, it can be an explosive hazard!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't continue to attempt to use the furnace until the problem is resolved.

You may have a clog in the air intake or exhaust, or a gas leak, or a problem with the pilot light or ignition system. I don't know much about furnaces, just mentioning these off the top of my head.

When it comes to explosive gas, calling in a professional to find the problem and perform the repair is a *really* good idea.